# Segmenting a Haskell list

Tags: list, haskell

Given a sorted list in haskell, how can I get segmented lists where the consecutive numbers are placed in the same list. For example if I have a sorted list `[1,2,3,4,7,8,10,12,13,15]` the result will be `[[1,2,3,4],[7,8],[10],[12,13],[15]]`

Comment: Maybe you can make `groupBy` do something useful?

Comment: Yes but not quite sure how to use it. I tried groupBy (\x y -> x-y == 1) [1,2,3,4,7,8,10,12,13,15] it gives me error!

Comment: try `import Data.List` and then your groupBy expression

Comment: the error is x and y are not in scope

Comment: `groupBy` doesn't work in this case anyhow, it tests the first element of the group against consecutive elements, not the last match against the next element. e.g. it would test `(1,2), (1,3)` not `(1,2), (2,3)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just a foldr:

```
q :: (Enum a, Eq a) => [a] -> [[a]]
q = foldr foo []
  where
    foo x (ys@(y:_) : zzs) | succ x == y = (x:ys) : zzs
    foo x t = [x] : t
```

> *Main> q [1,2,3,4,7,8,10,12,13,15]
>
> [[1,2,3,4],[7,8],[10],[12,13],[15]]

Update: It can also be turned into a foldl, here I use "difference lists" to make it go:

```
type N a = Maybe ( [[a]] -> [[a]], [a] -> [a], a )

p :: (Enum a, Eq a) => [a] -> [[a]]
p = close . foldl bar Nothing
  where
    close :: N a -> [[a]]
    close Nothing = []
    close (Just (f, g, _)) = (f  . (g []:)) []

    bar :: (Enum a, Eq a) => N a -> a -> N a
    bar Nothing x = Just (id, (x:), x)
    bar (Just (f, g, y)) x | succ y == x = Just (f, g . (x:), x)
                           | otherwise = Just ( f . (g []:), (x:), x)
```

Update 2 : 'f' is a variant that is safe on infinite lists:

```
f :: (Enum a, Eq a) => [a] -> [[a]]
f [] = []
f (x:xs) = go x xs
  where
    go x xs = let (run, rest) = getRun x xs
              in run : f rest
    getRun x t@(y:ys) | succ x == y = let (run, rest) = getRun y ys
                                      in (x:run, rest)
    getRun x t = (x:[], t)
```

or the shorter 'f' :

```
f :: (Enum a, Eq a) => [a] -> [[a]]
f [] = []
f (x:xs) = getRun x xs
  where
    getRun x t@(y:ys) | succ x == y = let (run : rest) = getRun y ys
                                      in (x:run) : rest
    getRun x t = (x:[]) : f t

t3 = [1,2,3,10,11,12] ++ [15..]
```

> *Main> take 3 (map (take 5) (f t3))
>
> [[1,2,3],[10,11,12],[15,16,17,18,19]]

Answer (score 1):

This function can help

```
addFirstInRun::Int->[Int]->[(Int, Int)]
addFirstInRun _ [] = []
addFirstInRun lowVal (x:y:rest) | y - x > 1 = (lowVal, x):firstInRun y (y:rest)
addFirstInRun lowVal (x:rest) = (lowVal, x):firstInRun lowVal rest
```

It pairs each value in the list with another number, the "head" of the current bin.

```
> addFirstInRun 1 [1,2,3,5,6,7,10]

  [(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(5,5),(5,6),(5,7),(10,10)]
```

(sorry, you need to put in the first one by hand....  you can write a convenience wrapper to fix this).

Using this, you can use `groupBy`

```
groupBy ((==) `on` fst)
```

And you can clean up the final answer using this

```
map (map snd)
```

Putting this all together

```
> map (map snd) $ groupBy ((==) `on` fst) $ addFirstInRun 1 [1,2,3,5,6,7,10]

  [[1,2,3],[5,6,7],[10]]
```

(You will need to import `Data.Function` and `Data.List`.)

Answer (score 1):

An outline of a solution:

1- Pair up each element with the next one:

```
(1,2) (2,3) (3,4) (4,7) (7,8) (8,10) (10,12) (12,13) (13,15) ...
```

2- Check each pair for being consecutive:

```
(1,2) (2,3) (3,4) (4,7) (7,8) (8,10) (10,12) (12,13) (13,15) ...
True  True  True  False True  False  False   True    False   ...
```

3- Break up the list at the `False` values:

```
(1,2) (2,3) (3,4) (4,7) | (7,8) (8,10) | (10,12) | (12,13) (13,15) | ...
True  True  True  False | True  False  | False   | True    False   | ...
```

4- For each segment take the `fst` of the pairs:

```
1 2 3 4 | 7 8 | 10 | 12 13
```